# Script only works on wordpress home page & only when Jqurery is aded using <script type="text/javascript" src="> but not when jquery is enqueued

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Script that is responsible for showing a scroll to the top button only works on WordPress  home page & only when Jqurery is added using `<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/themename/js/jquery.min.js">` but not when jquery is enqueued using

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script (
'jquery',
'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js',
array(),
null,
true);}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

And when it works i doesn't work on other pages except the home page.What could i be doing wrong? here is my script below

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// SCROLL BACK TO THE TOP ARROW

    $('.main_scroll_to_top').hide();
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(scroll_pos > 20){
            $('.main_scroll_to_top').fadeIn();
            //alert(scroll_pos);
        }
        if(scroll_pos < 20){
            $('.main_scroll_to_top').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    
    $('body').delegate("#main_scroll_to_top", 'click', function(event){
        var the_target = $(this).attr('the_target');
        //alert(the_target);
        var menu_offset = 30;
        if(the_target == 'content'){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 500);
            return false;
        }
        
    });
    
    

    
    });     


        
</script>
```

Ive also tried this example and the same thing happens

```
<a href="#" class="scrollToTop">↑</a>
<style>
.scrollToTop{
    font-size: 50px;
    width:100px; 
    height:130px;
    padding:10px; 
    text-align:center; 
    background: whiteSmoke;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:175px;
    right:5px;
    display:none;
    background: url('arrow_up.png') no-repeat 0px 20px;
}
.scrollToTop:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    
    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
    });
    
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you see when it doesn't work? Are there errors in the browser debug tools console? Where on the page is your scroll script? In particular is it included before or after jQuery? You're setting $in_footer = true in your enqueue line.

Comment: browser debug tools console Reports :                                                                     Loading failed for the <script> with source “localhost:8888/Antoinetta%20Model%20Management/index.php/Antoinetta/wp-content/themes/Antoinetta/js/jquery.min.js”. This error appears when loading on other pages ,it doesnt appear on home page. the scroll script is at the bottom of the page  within the footer